# Cloud Functions: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

I am getting sometimes, but frequently, an error on the Google Cloud Functions when I am listening to onWrite event.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
    at Firestore.snapshot_ (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/index.js:422:127)
    at beforeSnapshotConstructor (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/providers/firestore.js:140:30)
    at changeConstructor (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/providers/firestore.js:144:49)
    at cloudFunctionNewSignature (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:104:28)
    at cloudFunction (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:135:20)
    at /var/tmp/worker/worker.js:768:24
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:135:7)
```

As you can see, the issue is not related to my code, at least in the logs trace.

I set a console log at the top entry of the function, but it seems that the function does not even starts.

```
"dependencies": {
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "firebase-admin": "~6.0.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^2.1.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.11"
  },
```

Please any solution to this error or guides to its source?

Comment: I am having the same issue. The problem occurs infrequently, but there was a peak at the end of November, and there have been unusually many errors today. You could contact Firebase support so they can have a look at it.

Comment: I contact them, and it's related to a firebase incident due to an update made by their team. Now it's fixed.